# UV-Vis spectrum of 1,3-butadiene

Tags: physical-chemistry, group-theory, uv-vis-spectroscopy

[image]

Today I had the first lesson about UV-Vis spectrum. From the picture, the transition from HOMO to LUMOs of 1,3-butadiene depends on whether the structure is s-trans or s-cis.

My question is:

1. Why the π-π<sup>*</sup> transition from $\psi_2$ to $\psi_4$  is not allowed in s-trans conformation while it is a bit opposite for s-cis conformation
2. There is a slight change in wavelength of the transition from $\psi_2$  to $\psi_3$  in two conformation, while the transition from $\psi_2$  to $\psi^*_3$  remains the same value. Why is it so?

After Porphyrin's suggestion about symmetry of the transition, the only symmetry group that I could deduce is from the molecule itself, is there anyway to identify the symmetry of the orbital?

Comment: (1) the symmetry of the molecular orbitals between the ground state and the excited state in each point group, C2h for trans C2v for cis, determine if the transition is allowed for forbidden.  You need to know how to use point groups to work this out.

Comment: @porphyrin Its listed in the selection rule about the symmetry of the ground state and excited state. Is it the key to solve this problem?

Comment: yes. selection rules the symmetry properties of orbitals explains where these come from.