# 1,3-butadiene conformation difference

Tags: organic-chemistry, orbitals

I am aware that there are 2 well-known conformations of 1,3-butadiene which is s-cis and s-trans conformation.

[image]

The s-trans conformation is clearly more stable than the s-cis conformation whose interaction of two hydrogens destabilizes. Based on the picture in [Shira's question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/181011/uv-vis-spectrum-of-1-3-butadiene), the energy difference of the HOMO and LUMO in s-cis is lower than s-trans (calculated via wavelength). Why is that so? Could it be the contribution of the mentioned hydrogen interaction?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44053/relative-rates-of-two-acyclic-dienes-in-the-diels-alder-reaction

Comment: Much thanks for your suggestion, but I don't think think that I have the answer for the question